# How do I center my embedded youtube iframe?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a product landing page project and I can't figure out how to center the iframe youtube embedded video. I am trying to add this in my .css

I have tried using margin: auto auto auto auto; and am a bit stuck, thanks...

```css
    header{
text-align: center;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 50px;
margin-top: 30px;
}

    #header-img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 30px;
    }
  
    #header{
    

        

    }

    #video{
        margin: auto auto auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header">SCHIFRIN'S SPROCKETS
    <nav id:="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 1</a></li>

            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 2</a></li>

            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </header>

    <img src="./logo.png" alt="" id="header-img">

    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-MKbRSSHG8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the iframe in a div

```
<div class="frame">
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-MKbRSSHG8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and add css flexbox to that div

```
.frame{
    display: flex; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

just ajust width and height, you can remove them if you dont need them also.
This should be perfectly centered withing x and y axis

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in which you can achieve this. In my opinion, flexbox is the solution.

```css
header{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#header-img{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
  
#header{
    
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">SCHIFRIN'S SPROCKETS
    <nav id:="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 1</a></li>

            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 2</a></li>

            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </header>

    <img src="./logo.png" alt="" id="header-img">
  <div class="flex">
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-MKbRSSHG8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Wrap the iframe in a div and set its display property to flex.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #wrapper {
   text-align:center;
 }
#video{
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-MKbRSSHG8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your iframe in a div, and `text-align: center` that div to center the contents. Works well for adding a centered title to the youtube iframe as well.

And in case you want to embed multiple iframes on the page, you should use a `class` attribute instead of an `id` attribute.

```css
.videoWrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-MKbRSSHG8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```